# FindMaximum is not working properly?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to find maximum of the functions that I created by interpolating experimental data by using FindMaximum:

```
FindMaximum[{ii[x]}, {x, 41, 40, 57}, Method -> InteriorPoint]
```

but it works not very stable way. Here is the results of application of this function to 9 different curves. As you can see in the last curve it failed to find maximum, while the curve itself looks similar to others:

[image]

Any ideas why it happens and how I can fix it?

Comment: It looks like you're looking for a point `ii'[x]==0`? If yes try `NSolve[ii'[x]==0&&ii''[x]<0,40<x<60,x]`

Comment: If you provide no complete code and no data, we can provide no help...

Answer (score 2):

[FindMaximum](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindMaximum.html) searches for a local maximum. `FindMaximum` is working properly in your last example, it can find the global max in the bound value of your function. So, `FindMaximum` is working ok.

However, it looks like you're looking for points where your function has a local max.

For example, if your function is $\dfrac{\sin(10\pi x^{3})}{2x} + (x-1/2)^{4}$ and your range to search for the optimal values are from `-1.3` to `1.3`:

```
f = Sin[10 Pi x^3]/(2 x) + (x - 1/2)^4;
xLimits = {-1.3, 1.3};
```

You can use [WhenEvent](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent.html) and [NDSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve.html) to find the points where `f'[x] == 0`:

```
{sol, points} = 
  Reap@NDSolve[{y'[x] == D[f, x], 
     y[xLimits[[1]]] == (f /. x -> xLimits[[1]]), 
     WhenEvent[y'[x] == 0, Sow[{x, y[x]}]]}, 
    y[x], {x, xLimits[[1]], xLimits[[2]]}];
```

Plot the results:

```
Plot[f, {x, xLimits[[1]], xLimits[[2]]}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[Flatten[points, 1]]}, 
 PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image: Find all local max/min]

You can do something similar if you want only the max local values.

```
points = Select[Flatten[points, 1], (D[f, {x, 2}] /. x -> #[[1]]) < 0 &];
Plot[f, {x, xLimits[[1]], xLimits[[2]]}, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Red, Point[points]}, PlotPoints -> 20]
```

[image: Local max values]